# jQuery Validation Plugin + equalTo Not Working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Here is what I am currently using to attempt to validate a form.  When I press submit with no values entered into the form, I get the error messages for each of the inputs as expected.  However, no matter what I put in newpassword2 or newemail2 they never 'pass' validation.  I've tried everything from copy and paste to making them one letter each to no success.  Perhaps I am not using the equalTo attribute correctly...

I've also verified that all the names of the selectors agree with the input id's on the form.  Also, all of the inputs are contained within the form, so there aren't any outside of the form tags (I read that was an issue with someone else).

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#account_data").validate({ 
        rules: { 
            newpassword1: { required: true }, 
            newpassword2: { equalTo: "#newpassword1" },
            newemail1: { required: true, email: true },
            newemail2: { equalTo: "#newemail1" }
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: This question has been solved...almost by pure luck.  See below for updates.

Comment: If the question has been solved, you should accept the appropriate solution...

Answer (score 21):

If you will use id="password" it won't work. You must use another name for id.

All keys in the rules object refer to the `input.name` and not `input.id`

Comment: any explanation？ I can not see why after reading the source code.

Comment: I too am curious about the "why" here

Comment: From the source `staticRules[ element.name ] = existingRules;` all the keys in the `rules` object refer to the name of the form element

Comment: An `id` is not even required here.  The `equalTo` parameter simply must be a valid jQuery selector.  https://jsfiddle.net/drt2xqL4/

Answer (score 6):

Before using "equalTo" we need to take care of following points:

1. Use different word for input element name and id.
2. Use input element id in "equalTo" match instead of input element name:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                  $('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
                       $("form").validate({
                         rules: {
                            pwd: {
                                 required: true,
                                 minlength : 6
                             },
                            conf_pwd: {
                                   required: true,
                                   minlength : 6,
                                   equalTo: "#id_pwd"
                                 }
                        },
                        messages: {
                               pwd: {
                                  required: "Please enter the password.",
                                  minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters long"
                                },
                              conf_pwd: {
                                 required: "Please enter the confirm password.",
                                 minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters long",
                                 equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
                              }
                       },
                       submitHandler: function(form) {
                                 form.submit();
                        }
            });
                  });
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
       <div>
        <form id="data" action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group row">
        <label>Password:</label>
            <div>
            <input id="id_pwd" name="pwd" type="password" />
           </div>
        </div>
        <div>
        <label>Confirm Password:</label>
            <div>
            <input id="id_conf_pwd" name="conf_pwd" type="password" />
           </div>
        </div>
        <div>
        <div>
            <div>
      <input type="submit"  id="btnSubmit" name="submit" value="Reset Password">
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </form>
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Plz correct your code it should be `$("#form").validate({`

Comment: @Don'tDownvoteMe, it does not matter because his selector matches the `<form>` element itself.

Comment: However your `.validate()` call should not be inside of a click handler since the validate plugin is already capturing this click event.

Answer (score 2):

@Tom try

```
        newpassword1: { required: true }, 
        newpassword2: { required: true,equalTo: "#newpassword1"},
        newemail1: { required: true, email: true },
        newemail2: { required: true,email: true ,equalTo: "#newemail1" }
```

or use the latest version of validation plugin

Now rules have added with password being required set to true  and the second condition is for password_again set to required true and it has to “equalTo” the input field with id of password. With these conditions set, we are able to achieve what we are wanting. Do not forget to check the demo of the post to see how it works. For more documentation and resource on this plugin visit jQuery Validation Plugin

Comment: You know what? I got it to work with exactly the same code I posted in my original post.  All I changed was using both an id AND name for the form inputs.  I don't know if this is necessary, though, as name does not validate in (X)HTML Strict if I recall correctly.

Regardless, the validation plugin is working fine, and my question is now obsolete...sorry for wasting your time!

BTW, I added in the other attributes that you suggested and it still worked just fine!

THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!!!

-Tom-

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as Tom. The solution was to create an id for the password fields that matched the names for the password fields. (As mentioned by Tom). Definitely a bug in the validation code, because it should just rely on the name field. Oh well...

-Greg

Comment: Since the `equalTo` method simply takes a jQuery selector as it's parameter, `id` is absolutely not requiredl:  https://jsfiddle.net/drt2xqL4/