# jQuery Validate - Password confirmation equalTo doesnt work

Tags: jquery, forms, passwords, jquery-validate

im trying to do a form with password confirmation to compare the password repetition and give a error if the passwords are different using jquery.validate, my code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( "#formulario" ).validate({
       rules: {
                nombre: { required: true, number: false, minlength: 1 },
                email: { required: true, email: true },
                cp: { required: true, number: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 5 },
                password: { required: true, minlength: 6 },
                password2: { required: true, minlength: 6, equalTo: "#password" }
              },
       messages: {
                nombre: "Introduce un nombre correcto",
                email: "Introduce un email correcto",
                cp: "Introduce un codigo postal correcto",
                password: "la contraseña debe tener un minimo de 6 caracteres",
                password2: "las contraseñas tienen que ser iguales"
                }
       });
    });
</script>

<form id="formulario" method="post">
    <p>
      <label for="cp" class="hide">Nombre</label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" value="" id="nombre" class="required" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="email" class="hide">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" class="required" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="cp" class="hide">Codigo postal</label>
      <input type="text" name="cp" value="" id="cp" class="required" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="password" class="hide">Contraseña</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="required"/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="password2" class="hide">rrrr Contraseña</label>
      <input type="password" name="password2" value="" id="password2" class="required" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Enviar</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

What im doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6Rx4L/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887292/jquery-validation-plugin-equalto-not-working

Comment: Its not working on my local, i dont know why

Comment: Missing the document ready handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is solved, i changed this:

```
$( "#formulario" ).validate({
```

to this:

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#formulario").validate({
```

Now it's working, thanks ppl

Comment: You were missing the DOM ready event handler, which means that your jQuery code was trying to run before the elements were fully constructed in the DOM.  Your fix above is correct, and it's how you should always be enclosing any jQuery on the page.